# Extending barycentric coordinates

Tags: python, api, coordinates, maya

Basically I had posted this question, [Joint Weight Interpolation Maya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166845/joint-weight-interpolation-maya/24170034#24170034). I got this working similar to the copy skin weights with maya. Unfortunately this only works with triangles and isn't quite the same as maya's method. How can I extend this barycentric coordinates to work with a polygon? Is there a method that allows you to get barycentric coordinates per triangle and sort of sum up the values from there? I know maya has some answer for getting linear interpolation per point inside a polygon, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/MHBD02.pdf) is the  paper i should be referencing but perhaps the math is a bit above my head.

Answer (score 1):

What I've ended up doing for this was implementing [this](http://cgvr.cs.uni-bremen.de/papers/barycentric/barycentric.pdf) and it seems to work accordingly with maya's copy skin weights. I do have it check if the polygon is convex and if it is it'll just use regular barycentric coordinates on a closest triangle.

Here's and update based on @Paul's request. I scrounged this up and hope it helps. I think this was a really early test I did.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pnts = []

    p1 = OpenMaya.MVector(*cmds.xform("p0",
                          query=True,
                          worldSpace=True,
                          translation=True))

    p2 = OpenMaya.MVector(*cmds.xform("p1",
                          query=True,
                          worldSpace=True,
                          translation=True))

    p3 = OpenMaya.MVector(*cmds.xform("p2",
                          query=True,
                          worldSpace=True,
                          translation=True))

    p4 = OpenMaya.MVector(*cmds.xform("p3",
                          query=True,
                          worldSpace=True,
                          translation=True))
    p5 = OpenMaya.MVector(*cmds.xform("p4",
                          query=True,
                          worldSpace=True,
                          translation=True))
    pnts.append(p1)
    pnts.append(p2)
    pnts.append(p3)
    pnts.append(p4)
    pnts.append(p5)

    p = OpenMaya.MVector(*cmds.xform("p",
                         query=True,
                         worldSpace=True,
                         translation=True))

    vertCount = len(pnts)

    weights = []

    si = []
    for i, pnt in enumerate(pnts):
        si.append(pnts[i] - p)

    Ri = []
    Ai = []
    Di = []

    for i, pnt in enumerate(pnts):

        iPlus = (i+1) % vertCount

        ri = si[i].length()
        ai = (si[i] ^ si[iPlus]).length()/2.0
        di = si[i] * si[iPlus]

        if round(ri, 7) == 0.0:
            print("%s : 1.0." % i)
            Ri = []
            Ai = []
            Di = []
            break

        elif round(ai, 7) == 0.0 and round(di, 7) < 0.0:
            riPlus = si[iPlus].length()
            print("%s : %s" % (i, ri/(ri+riPlus)))
            print("%s : %s" % (iPlus, riPlus/(ri+riPlus)))
            Ri = []
            Ai = []
            Di = []
            break

        else:
            Ri.append(ri)
            Ai.append(ai)
            Di.append(di)

    if not len(Ri) == 0 or not len(Ai) == 0 or not len(Di) == 0:

        for i, pnt in enumerate(pnts):

            iPlus = (i+1) % vertCount
            iMinus = (i-1) % vertCount

            w = 0.0

            if not Ai[iMinus] == 0.0:
                w += (Ri[iMinus] - Di[iMinus] / Ri[i]) / Ai[iMinus]

            if not Ai[i] == 0.0:
                w += (Ri[iPlus] - Di[i] / Ri[i]) / Ai[i]

            weights.append(w)

        weightSum = sum(weights)
        finalWeights = [weight/weightSum for weight in weights]

        print("Weights: ", finalWeights)
```

Comment: Would be great if you could extend your answer a bit. For example, how did you implement the determinant `Ai := det(si, si+1)/2` ? Shouldn't a determinant be computed on a square matrix?